# Fastest way to insert many documents to Mongodb using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I need to create a script that will inspect a C# list and then create and insert approximately 320,000 mongodb documents.  Currently I am using a foreach loop creates the C# class that represents the mongo document, adds the document to a batch, and when the batch size reaches 99999, I insert the batch to the database.  Despite the use of the batch inserts, my script needs about 4 hours to complete, which is way too slow.

```
            foreach (var r in result)
            {
                var newdoc = new UserMailingList
                {
                    UserId = new Guid(r.rcid),
                    MailingListId = listid,
                    StatusId = 0,
                    IsDeleted = false,
                    Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow
                };
                batch.Add(newdoc);
                batchsize++;
                if (batchsize == 99999)
                {
                    collection.insertmany(batch)
                    batchsize = 0;
                    batch.Clear();
                }
            }
```

Is there a faster way to do this with the C# mongo client, or is there away to generate the javascript code that represents my batch insert(s), so that I can paste it directly into the mongo client?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to parallize your batch inserts. MongoDB acts very well with more than one client connection. Make also use of the c# drivers async api („InsertManyAsync“ a.s.o.) while parallizing.

Btw, MongoDB batches by 1000 docs, even if your doc count is greater than that.

Other points to consider when talking about „these database operations are taking too long“ are database (server) metrics. Is your db on heavy load, Is your hdd fast enough to handle disk io that fast.

Here are some more things to think about
[Bulk insert performance in MongoDB for large collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736231/bulk-insert-performance-in-mongodb-for-large-collections)

PS: 320000 docs seems not that much. Our mongo server is continuously writing 3000 .. 10000 docs every 2 seconds. And note, no special hardware (6xvCPU a2,2GHz, 10GB RAM, SAN with Hybrid of SSD and old style HDD). If you restart your mongod process and the execution of your script right after that is suddenly significantly faster, then I guess your server is under pressure (mongodb slows down after some time if it can not handle / follow DML operations).