# Insert 271 million records to MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have 271 million records, line by line in a text file that I need to add to MongoDB, and I'm using Python and Pymongo in order to do this.

I first split the single file containing the 271 million records into multiple files containing each 1 million lines, and have written the current code to add it to the database:

```
import os
import threading
from pymongo import MongoClient


class UserDb:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
        self.data = self.client.large_data.data


threadlist = []

def start_add(listname):
    db = UserDb()
    with open(listname, "r") as r:
        for line in r:
            if line is None:
                return
            a = dict()
            a['no'] = line.strip()
            db.data.insert_one(a)
    print(listname, "Done!")


for x in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if x.startswith('li'):
        t = threading.Thread(target=start_add, args=(x,))
        t.start()
        threadlist.append(t)

print("All threads started!")


for thread in threadlist:
    thread.join()
```

This starts as many threads as there are files, and adds every line to the db as it goes through it. The bad thing is that after 3 hours it had only added 8.630.623.

What can I do to add the records faster?

One row of data is just 8 digits: (e.g. 12345678)

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736231/bulk-insert-performance-in-mongodb-for-large-collections?

Comment: Performance problems can be caused by many things.  The first thing I would look at is disk performance using IOSTAT.  Many times these types of things are bound up by queuing at the hard drive.  If hardware is the problem, you can upgrade hardware (scale horizontally), or add computers via sharding (scale horizontally).  Other things to look at include the document schema itself and can it be improved.  Also, try to see if network bottlenecks are occurring...

Comment: If your data is csv or json, look at [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing multiple `insert_one`s, take a look a the [bulk write operators](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html).

Play around a little to see what works best; I've found batches of 10,000 work for me, but this is hardware dependant.