# How does MongoDB deal with Object ID overlap when mongorestore?

Tags: database, mongodb

I'm trying to insert bunch of data into separate collections in order to reduce the insert time.
So, afterwards, I would get dump from them and restore a single new collection to have all the data.
I guess this is weird itself prior to my question below.

Here my concern is about what if Object ID overlap occurs.
MongoDB, say there are 1st one (already inserted) and 2nd one (to be inserted) that have Object ID in common, would give an error for the 2nd one and exit execution,
just ignore (not likely), or replace the Object ID for the 2nd one (seems odd, in that the ID is primary key).

At any chance, the solution in this case is "sharding", no concerns for ID overlap?
But I know nothing about sharding yet in term of any setup and so on to use, so I do not expect I could use very soon.

Comment: Perfect reference about mongorestore, thanks. BTW, I need to check there is any parameter to name a file that has skipped document `_id`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB (standalone) is very bound in capacity compare to a cluster (shareds). If you want to increase insertion thoughput in the standalone mode you wont achieve much. If you throughput in multiple collections in a single standalone database is fine then it will be fine into a single collection. The second, insert + dump + insert is definitely slower than just insert in a single collection. So I recommend reconsider your solution. And yes, _id is an unique field by default, thus trying to insert multiple object with a sinle _id will cause an error.

Comment: Okay, now I consider the way to do parallel insertion by multi processing, I'm using Python, into a single collection. Each document is often close to document limit, so I need to see how well it works, though.

Comment: you can use parallel insertion, still as long as you are on a single instace of database, you wont gain much (mb even nothing) from parallel insertion, does not matter if that is a single collection or multiple. When you have a cluster you get a speed gain from every new shard inserting into a single collection.

Answer (score 0):

The case where two documents of different collections have same ObjectId is very unlikely as objectId is made from random values also. Please check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

To answer the question if you want increase insertion speed, may be check bulk insertion, its definitely faster and setting correct write concerns if you have replicas enabled will improve insertion speed.

Comment: Thanks, but I did recognize and fully agree that `_id` overlap is VERY unlikey to happen. I just considered as an accident. And, my documents are quite large in current scheme having hundreds of thousands of key-values. According to this one, it's not sure for bulk insertion to help me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736231/bulk-insert-performance-in-mongodb-for-large-collections

Comment: Personally when such cases arise, we follow below steps.
Remove all constraints and indexes from mongo collection where you want to insert and then just use parallel writes using threading or multiprocessing. It generally helps. Also if document is large consider changing the data model.